# Regular expression to parse pipe-delimited data enclosed in double braces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match a string like this:

```
{{name|arg1|arg2|...|argX}}
```

with a regular expression

I'm using `preg_match` with

```
/{{(\w+)\|(\w+)(?:\|(.+))*}}/
```

but I get something like this, whenever I use more than two args

```
Array
(
    [0] => {{name|arg1|arg2|arg3|arg4}}
    [1] => name
    [2] => arg1
    [3] => arg2|arg3|arg4
)
```

The first two items cannot contain spaces, the rest can.
Perhaps I'm working too long on this, but I can't find the error - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Jan

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regular expressions for these kind of simple tasks. What you really need is:

```
$inner = substr($string, 2, -2);
$parts = explode('|', $inner);

# And if you want to make sure the string has opening/closing braces:
$length = strlen($string);
assert($inner[0] === '{');
assert($inner[1] === '{');
assert($inner[$length - 1] === '}');
assert($inner[$length - 2] === '}');
```

Comment: Okay, I have to clarify then:
<br />
I'm trying to match an unknown number of said expressions in a html template page.
so an easy substr is not a possibility...
<br />
but you gave me an idea ;)
<br />
I'm going to use the regex to find {{([^}]+)}} and then continue with the explode.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a rather lazy answer and turns a simple task into writing a million checks if you really want to be sure.
And instead of stripping the brackets by substringing, why not do a str_replace( array( '{','}' ), '', $string );

Comment: This answer was written before the clarification. And using str_replace() does not let you **verify** that the brackets are in the string.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here: \|(.+)

Regular expressions, by default, match as many characters as possible. Since . is any character, other instances of | are happily matched too, which is not what you would like.

To prevent this, you should exclude | from the expression, saying "match anything except |", resulting in \|([^\|]+).

Answer (score 0):

Should work for anywhere from 1 to *N* arguments

```
<?php

$pattern = "/^\{\{([a-z]+)(?:\}\}$|(?:\|([a-z]+))(?:\|([a-z ]+))*\}\}$)/i";

$tests = array(
    "{{name}}"                          // should pass
  , "{{name|argOne}}"                   // should pass
  , "{{name|argOne|arg Two}}"           // should pass
  , "{{name|argOne|arg Two|arg Three}}" // should pass
  , "{{na me}}"                         // should fail
  , "{{name|arg One}}"                  // should fail
  , "{{name|arg One|arg Two}}"          // should fail
  , "{{name|argOne|arg Two|arg3}}"      // should fail
  );

foreach ( $tests as $test )
{
  if ( preg_match( $pattern, $test, $matches ) )
  {
    echo $test, ': Matched!<pre>', print_r( $matches, 1 ), '</pre>';
  } else {
    echo $test, ': Did not match =(<br>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you would get something like this :) There is no way in regular expression to return dynamic count of matches - in your case the arguments.

Looking at what you want to do, you should keep up with the current regular expression and just explode the extra args by '|' and add them to an args array.

Answer (score 0):

indeed, this is from PCRE manual:

> When a capturing subpattern is
>   repeated, the value captured is the
>   substring that matched the final
>   iteration. For example, after
>   (tweedle[dume]{3}\s*)+  has matched
>   "tweedledum tweedledee" the value of
>   the captured substring is
>   "tweedledee". However, if there are
>   nested capturing subpatterns, the
>   corresponding captured values may have
>   been set in previous iterations. For
>   example, after /(a|(b))+/  matches
>   "aba" the value of the second captured
>   substring is "b".